# Network DFS Shares Jumping Back To Root

Tags: windows, active-directory, dfs

I have a DFS-R namespace with three nodes. Two of the nodes work just fine, but a third node does something very strange.

When you are browsing the node through the namespace, when you change into a folder it dumps you out of the folder and back where you were moments before. Sometimes it then dumps you out of *that* folder and you watch as you work your way back up the directory tree.

I apologise for the animated gif, but it looks like this when it happens:

> ![enter image description here][1]

1. In the `apps` node of the namespace
2. Change into the "MYOB" directory
3. After about 1 second, are dumped back in the `apps` node

What could be causing this? Node is Server 2012 R2.